# Execute process in Runc container via Garden API

Tags: cloud-foundry, runc, garden-runc

I have a [Cloud Foundry Bosh Lite](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/diego-release/tree/develop/examples/bosh-lite) install with [Garden/Runc support](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/garden-runc-release) running on my local dev machine with an app hosted on it. I can ssh into the Diego cell VM and execute

```
cell_z1/0# runc exec 5f9c8b67-9170-4c53-4bab-bbb2e6a3acdf /usr/bin/printenv
```

This will produce the following output:

```
INSTANCE_GUID=5f9c8b67-9170-4c53-4bab-bbb2e6a3acdf
INSTANCE_INDEX=0
CF_INSTANCE_GUID=5f9c8b67-9170-4c53-4bab-bbb2e6a3acdf
CF_INSTANCE_INDEX=0
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
CF_INSTANCE_CERT=/etc/cf-instance-credentials/instance.crt
CF_INSTANCE_KEY=/etc/cf-instance-credentials/instance.key
HOME=/root
```

I assumed I could achieve the same through the [Garden API](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/garden/blob/master/doc/garden-api.md) by invoking

```
cell_z1/0# curl -X POST -d '{"path":"/usr/bin/printenv"}' localhost:7777/containers/5f9c8b67-9170-4c53-4bab-bbb2e6a3acdf/processes
```

However, this will return

```
{"Type":"","Message":"EOF","Handle":""}
```

which unfortunately tells me nothing. I tried adding `"user":"vcap"` in the JSON payload but the result is the same. When I add `-H "Content-Type: application/json" -d` I get

```
curl: (56) Problem (2) in the Chunked-Encoded data
```

**Question:** how can I execute an arbitrary command inside a container via the Garden API and retrieve it's output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Go Library**

The supported way to execute commands within a Garden container is via the [Go client library](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/garden). For example:

```
gdnClient := client.New(connection.New("tcp", "127.0.0.1:7777"))

container, err := gdnClient.Create(garden.ContainerSpec{})
if err != nil {
  os.Exit(1)
}

buffer := &bytes.Buffer{}
process, err := container.Run(garden.ProcessSpec{
  Path: "/usr/bin/printenv",
}, garden.ProcessIO{
  Stdout: buffer,
  Stderr: buffer,
})
if err != nil {
  os.Exit(1)
}

exitCode, err := process.Wait()
if err != nil {
  os.Exit(1)
}

fmt.Printf("Exit code: %d, Process output %s", exitCode, buffer.String())
```

**Gaol CLI**

If you would prefer not to write any Go code you can use the unsupported (but very useful) [Gaol CLI](https://github.com/contraband/gaol). For example:

```
gaol create -n myContainer
gaol run -c "/usr/bin/printenv" myContainer
```

Ensure that you set your `GAOL_TARGET` appropriately e.g. 10.244.16.6:7777 on bosh-lite if you are running from your dev machine.

**HTTP Clients**

Finally, it is technically feasible to work with the entire Garden API through any HTTP client, but the supported client/server libraries do some connection hijacking which might confuse things. In particular, running a process is the most complicated API interaction.

Firstly, a [request](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/garden/blob/master/client/connection/connection.go#L172) is made to the run endpoint and then the connection is [hijacked](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/garden/blob/master/client/connection/connection_hijacker.go#L84). The garden client starts [streaming](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/garden/blob/master/client/connection/connection.go#L208) stdio for the process by using the hijacked connection for stdin and hitting two other [endpoints](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/garden/blob/master/server/server.go#L92-L93).

It shouldn't be too hard to get a process running in a container, requiring only a json encoded [`garden.ProcessSpec`](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/garden/blob/06cf1e670d97a5b83c91571b4460bb9b7e61b0bf/container.go#L135-L157) in the request body but streaming the output is quite a bit trickier.

Comment: Thanks. I'd really like to do this via curl or some Java HTTP client library though. I can access the various GET endpoints like api/containers/:id:/info and such just fine. If running a processes via the API is not possible with a regular HTTP client lib for some reason, I'll fallback to invoking runc directly.

Comment: I will update my answer with some more information about that

Comment: If you are having troubles, I would suggest joining the #garden channel in the Cloud Foundry slack and collecting the garden logs from `/var/vcap/sys/log/garden/garden.std{out,err}.log`